# Does the existence of no minimal base $(X, \tau) $ implies it is a non discrete $T_1$ space?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

$(X, \tau) $ be a topological space and suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $X$ for the topology $\tau$.

It can be shown that if $\tau$ define a non discrete $T_1$ topology on $X$ , then $X$ can't have a minimal base for the topology $\tau$.i.e  for any basis $\mathcal{B}$ there exists $\mathcal{B}'\subsetneq \mathcal{B}$ which is also a basis.

My Question : Suppose the topological space $(X, \tau) $ such that $X$ has no minimal base for the topology $\tau$ . Does this implies $(X, \tau) $ a non discrete $T_1$ space.

Comment: Do you want to exclude trivial counterexamples constructed by doing things like replacing one point with two topologically indistinguishable points (to make it not $T_1$) or taking a disjoint union with a non-$T_1$ space?

Comment: Yes. It's better to avoid trivial one.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how to formulate the question precisely to avoid that sort of thing—those are just a couple examples of that sort of construction I thought of on the spot, but it seems like there's lots of ways to slightly modify a non-discrete $T_1$ space to obtain a space that isn't $T_1$ but still has no minimal base for the topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are tons of non-$T_1$ topologies that have no minimal basis (and are not just a small modification of a $T_1$ space).  For a simple example, take $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology consisting of the empty set and the sets $U_x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:y>x\}$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This is very far from $T_1$ (no subspace with more than one point is $T_1$!) but I claim it has no minimal basis.  Indeed, a collection of sets $U_x$ form a basis iff the corresponding $x$ values are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ remains dense if you remove an element.